# macOS 10.13.1 High Sierra Disk Space iMac

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-space

I cannot determine what could possibly be taking up so much of my 1TB startup disk.

I have moved most applications to another disk and moved home directories and still receive your disk is almost full and now can not run timemachine backups with an error:

> Time Machine could not create a local snapshot to back up from because
>   there was insufficient free space on the source volume(s).

In a terminal running as root executing:
root# du -cshm /Volumes/org-disk/*/

```
8610    /Volumes/org-disk/Applications/
8787    /Volumes/org-disk/Library/
0   /Volumes/org-disk/Network/
7044    /Volumes/org-disk/System/
1   /Volumes/org-disk/User Information/
23  /Volumes/org-disk/Users/
4825673 /Volumes/org-disk/Volumes/
3   /Volumes/org-disk/bin/
0   /Volumes/org-disk/cores/
1   /Volumes/org-disk/dev/
2   /Volumes/org-disk/etc/
1   /Volumes/org-disk/home/
1   /Volumes/org-disk/net/
du: /Volumes/org-disk/private//var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/private//var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000y800007k/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/private//var/folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/private//var/folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/private//var/folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/private//var/folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
3832    /Volumes/org-disk/private/
2   /Volumes/org-disk/sbin/
4   /Volumes/org-disk/ssud_installation/
3   /Volumes/org-disk/tmp/
1799    /Volumes/org-disk/usr/
du: /Volumes/org-disk/var//db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/var//folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000y800007k/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/var//folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/var//folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/var//folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/org-disk/var//folders/jw/vtq0s2z94kv6jfsh6c1mr9d80000gn/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
3828    /Volumes/org-disk/var/
4859601 total
```

Implies I am using 4,859,601MB or about 1/2 of the space on the drive.

Finder says there is 1.09 GB available.

Where is the missing space?

As this is an iMAC replacing the internal drive is not a simple solution.

Any ideas?